# Mockito: verify function being called with an argument that has deep nested objects

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have this class and a unit test to verify a function being called with an argument which is a list of objects that has nested objects.

```
   @Data
   class Test {
      private String name;
      private User user;
   }

   @Data
   class User {
       private String name;
   }


   service.somemethod(List.of(
                new Test("test1", new User("user1")),
                new Test("test1", new User("user1"))
            ));
```

My test code:

```
Service spyService = Mockito.spy(service);
  verify(spyService, times(1)).somemethod(eq(List.of(
                new Test("test1", new User("user1")),
                new Test("test1", new User("user1"))
            )));
```

This will give me an error that User does not match. I see it is trying to compare User by address instead of value. How can I make it so that it will compare the nested object by value? I tried adding `eq()` around `new User()` but it throws another error saying eq can't be used there

Comment: `trying to compare User by address instead of value` there is no address in your code snippet

Comment: @AdamSiemion I updated the question with more code. I'm trying say is that the `new User("user1")` is not being compared based on the property values, instead it was compared based on whether it is the same reference

Answer (score 0):

if you create seprate list variable and passed it to the spied function and to the verify function it will work:

```
@Test
public void test_spy_2() {
    
    BusinessImpl businessImpl_spied = spy(BusinessImpl.class);
    
    List<Depratment> list = List.of(
            new Test("test1", new User("user1")),
            new Test("test1", new User("user1"))
        );
    
    businessImpl_spied.testCallList(list);
    
    verify(businessImpl_spied).testCallList(ArgumentMatchers.eq(list));
    
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my test method has no access to the list that is passed in to the original function.